# Android video not valid for streaming

Tags: android, video-streaming

i'm trying following code playing video.

```
public class VidplayerActivity extends Activity {

    private MediaController mc;
    String LINK = "http://***/test.3gp"; // 5 mb 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            VideoView vd = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.delta);

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(LINK);

            mc = new MediaController(this);
            vd.setMediaController(mc);

            vd.setVideoURI(uri);
            vd.start();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
        }
    }

}
```

it shows **"Sorry,this video is not valid for streaming to this device"** in android 1.5 and 1.6. And the video details is below

**EDIT:**

> Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from
>   '/home/cvbcvb/Desktop/test.3gp':
>
> Metadata:
>
> ```
> major_brand     : 3gp4
>
> minor_version   : 512
>
> compatible_brands: isomiso23gp4
> ```
>
> Duration: 00:03:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 150 kb/s
>
> ```
> Stream #0.0(und): Video: h263, yuv420p, 176x144 [PAR 12:11 DAR
> ```
>
> 4:3], 138 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 29.97 tbc
>
> ```
> Stream #0.1(und): Audio: amrnb, 8000 Hz, 1 channels, flt, 8 kb/s
> ```
>
> [STREAM]
>
> index=0
>
> codec_name=h263
>
> codec_long_name=H.263 / H.263-1996, H.263+ / H.263-1998 / H.263
>   version 2
>
> codec_type=video
>
> codec_time_base=1001/30000
>
> codec_tag_string=s263
>
> codec_tag=0x33363273
>
> width=176
>
> height=144
>
> has_b_frames=0
>
> sample_aspect_ratio=12:11
>
> display_aspect_ratio=4:3
>
> pix_fmt=yuv420p
>
> r_frame_rate=25/1
>
> avg_frame_rate=25/1
>
> time_base=1/25
>
> language=und
>
> start_time=0.000000
>
> duration=180.040000
>
> nb_frames=4501
>
> TAG:language=und
>
> [/STREAM]
>
> [STREAM]
>
> index=1
>
> codec_name=amrnb
>
> codec_long_name=Adaptive Multi-Rate NarrowBand
>
> codec_type=audio
>
> codec_time_base=0/1
>
> codec_tag_string=samr
>
> codec_tag=0x726d6173
>
> sample_rate=8000.000000
>
> channels=1
>
> bits_per_sample=0
>
> r_frame_rate=0/0
>
> avg_frame_rate=0/0
>
> time_base=1/8000
>
> language=und
>
> start_time=0.000000
>
> duration=180.000000
>
> nb_frames=9000
>
> TAG:language=und
>
> [/STREAM]

Answer (score 1):

Please read this document : [Android Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).
Just being encoded using `H 263` it is not enough for be in a valid format for streaming in Android.

The resolutions has to be : `176 x 144 px` or `480 x 360 px` and also at the bottom of the documentation it is stated:

> For video content that is streamed over HTTP or RTSP, there are additional requirements:
>
> For 3GPP and MPEG-4 containers, the moov atom must precede any mdat atoms.
>
> For 3GPP, MPEG-4, and WebM containers, audio and video samples corresponding to the same time offset may be no more than 500 KB apart. To minimize this audio/video drift, consider interleaving audio and video in smaller chunk sizes.

Comment: are you using a real device or you are testing on the emulator?

Comment: this may be the problem then. since the emulator has a reduced performance, you should try on some real devices and they should work. I had similar issues too.

Answer (score 0):

**try this ::**

```
   mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);

        if (path == "") {
            // Tell the user to provide a media file URL/path.
            Toast.makeText(
                    VideoViewDemo.this,
                    "Please edit VideoViewDemo Activity, and set path"
                            + " variable to your media file URL/path",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {


            mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
            mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
            mVideoView.requestFocus();
```

**videoview.xml**

```
<VideoView 
    android:id="@+id/surface_view" 
    android:layout_width="320px"
    android:layout_height="240px"
/>
```

[**And also view this**](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Media/Video/)